# Switching url upon tab switching in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I apologize if my title doesn't quite explain my issue and what I'm trying to complete. So I have a login page for a site I'm building and on the login page, I added a tab which is really another div that upon pressing the Register "tab" a piece of jquery handles the clickevent and switches to the new div. This is the code for the switching.

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $('#login-link').click(function (e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#register-link').click(function (e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

And this is the div that holds the "tabs"

```
div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <a href="/login/login" class="active" id="login-link">Login</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="/login/register" id="register-link">Register</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

For each of the divs, login and register, they are each their own form, and handled by a servlet using `action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/` to pass the parameters from the jsp to servlet upon a submit event.

My issue and what I'm having a ton of trouble figuring out is how to make when switching to the div, whether from login to register or vise versa, is to change the url of the page. The reason for this is that the servlet passes errors to the jsp and I can't display them properly since switching to the other div contains the incorrect link.

I believe the way to do this is through javascript/jquery but I can't seem to find a way to do this. There may even be an entirely better way to do this that I'm completely unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the way to change the window URL on URL bar, when user moves from login form to registeration form or vice versa. If you are targeting the browsers which support HTML5 than you can do so by `history.pushSate()` API.

Using `history.pushState()` API manipualates the browser history locally, but it should be noted that, changes made in `history` using this API will not load the page, when you click on `Back` or `Forward` button of browser. In this case you will have to add another event listener `popstate`, and explicitely call `window.reload()` to load web page from web server. I am providing the document links and example links here, so that until you are not 100% confident in the pros and cons of this API, you may introduce app usage headach for user.

More about `history` APIs is well documented at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). Also example is explained at [CSS-TRICKS](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/)